# How to disable a user control on main window from page WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a user control sitting on my main window, It is a menu.

When a user tries editing objects on a page I want to disable this user control while the user is on edit mode so they do not navigate off the page they are editing.

I am having trouble accessing the user control(placed on the main window) from a page

User Control Name - MenuView

The code below is on the page load of the page

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.MenuView.IsEnabled = false;
```

This does not seem to work though

Comment: Bind IsEnabled property to a property of your viewmodel that tells if the user is editing or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the existing instance of the `MainWindow` instead of creating a new one.

If you don't care about MVVM, the easiest way to do this would probably be to use the static `Application.Current.Windows` or `App.Current.MainWindow` property:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault(); 
if (mainWindow != null)
    mainWindow.MenuView.IsEnabled = false;
```

Note that this approach does create a coupling between your classes, but this is inevitable if you access a field of the window from in the `Page` class.

You probably want to look into the MVVM design pattern but that's another story.

Comment: My intention was to try this but went wrong somewhere along the line. Your solution works perfectly. thanks